# ¿como realizar inputs de forma automatica en java?

Tags: java, netbeans, jsp, java-8, netbeans-8.2

Quiero testear la velocidad de un algoritmo a la hora de leer los datos de entrada de cierto programa, para ello no quiero que factores externos como el tiempo en que tarde en ingresar los valores afecten el resultado de mi prueba por eso necesito ingresar los datos de forma automática por ejemplo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    { 
        Reader in=new Reader(); 
        for(int i = 0 ;i<100;i++){
                int j = in.nextInt();        
        }
    }
```

y con mis datos de entrada ya listos no tenga necesidad yo de digitarlos uno por uno.

IMPORTANTE:(Primero guardar los datos en un arreglo no es una opción ya que lo que quiero testear es la velocidad con la que el programa lee los datos)

Comment: quieres leer los datos de un archivo?

Comment: Que quieres leer?? Un archivo, flujo de datos, o datos de un formulario??

Comment: Quiero leer datos ingresados manualmente, como se haría con Scanner, pero busco "simular" de alguna manera el funcionamiento de los compiladores onlines, en los cuales uno puede pre-ingresar la entrada y a la hora de ejecutarse no tenga que ingresar dato por dato manualmente

Comment: ¿Estás utilizando `JUnit`?

Answer (score 0):

Dándole una vuelta, creo que esto valdría para lo que buscas, aunque recomiendo que eches un ojo al framework [`JUnit`](https://junit.org/junit5/) para pruebas de este tipo.

```
package autoinputtest;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AutoInputTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String [] datos = new String[100]; // Declarar array con datos
        InputStream is = null; // Con InputStream abrimos un flujo de bytes de lectura

        for (int i = 0;i < datos.length; i++) {
            try { 
                is = System.in;
                datos[i] = i + " - input test"; // Rellenar array para simular entradas de texto
                System.setIn(new ByteArrayInputStream(datos[i].getBytes())); // ByteArrayInputStream -> permite leer bytes del buffer de memoria 
                Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println(entrada.nextLine());
                System.setIn(is); // Reasignar flujo de entrada 
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```